# Mandar un mensaje a múltiples contactos con Whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, whatsapp, whatsapp-web

Hola estoy haciendo un código para enviar un mensaje a todos mis contactos, he podido enviar un mensaje a una lista de contactos dentro de un array, ¿alguien sabe una forma de automatizar esto, por ejemplo enviar un mensaje a mis primeros 5 contactos, o a todos mis contactos?

Aquí está mi código:

```
const myChats = ["Prueba 1", "Prueba 2"];

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Client is ready!');
client.getChats().then((chats)=>{

    myChats.forEach((chatName,i) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
        const myChat = chats.find((chat) => chat.name === chatName);
        if(myChat){
          client.sendMessage(myChat.id._serialized, "Message with 10 seconds delay"); 
        }
        else {
          console.log(`Chat ${chatName} not found`);
        }
    },i*10000); //delay to not send the message at the same time to avoid been blocked
      });
});
```

});

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, estaría muy agradecido, muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: A manda un mensaje multiple, te refieres a una especie de bot? o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Si es correcto sería una especie bot